# How to preselect a value in React Native's Picker component based on a selected item?

Tags: react-native, navigation, state, parameter-passing, picker

I'm working on a React Native app where I have a list of teams displayed in a screen (TeamsScreen). When a user taps on a team, I want to navigate to another screen (NewMessageScreen) where a Picker component is present, and the selected team should be preselected in the Picker.

In TeamsScreen, I have a handleNewMessage function that is triggered when a team is selected. Here's the code:

```
  handleNewMessage = (team) => {
    console.log("Selected Team:", team.Team);
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    navigation.navigate('NewMessage', { teamId: team.TID, selectedTeam: team }); // Pass the selected team object to the NewMessageScreen
  };
```

In NewMessageScreen, I'm receiving the selected team object through navigation parameters and want to use it to preselect the value in the Picker component. Here's the code:

```
class NewMessageScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      dataSource: [],
      refresh: true,
      DarkBlue: '#183b78',
      LtBlue: '#183b78',
      Green: '#5cb85c',
      Yellow: '#183b78',
      Red: '#d9534f',
      Gray: '#aaa',
      fontLoaded: false,
      isLoading: true,
      isVisible: false,
      PickerValueHolder: '0',
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.refresh();
    const { navigation, route } = this.props;
    const teamId = route.params.teamId;
    console.log("Selected Team ID:", teamId); // Log the selected team's ID
    if (teamId) {
      const selectedItem = this.state.dataSource.find(item => item.tid === teamId);
      if (selectedItem) {
        this.setState({ PickerValueHolder: selectedItem.tid });
      }
    }
  }
```

And here is the code for the picker:

```
<Picker
                    style={styles.picker}
                    itemStyle={styles.pickerItem}
                    selectedValue={this.state.PickerValueHolder}
                    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
                        console.log("Selected Team:", itemValue); // Log the selected team
                        const selectedTeam = this.state.dataSource.find(item => item.tid === itemValue);
                        console.log("Selected Team Object:", selectedTeam); // Log the selected team object
                        this.setState({ PickerValueHolder: itemValue });
                    }}
                    >
                    <Picker.Item label="Please select a recipient." value="0" />
                    {this.state.dataSource.map(item => (
                        <Picker.Item label={item.teamSelector} value={item.tid} key={item.tid} />
                    ))}
                    </Picker>
```

The picker is console.log'ing all of the team's information when I manually select it (including the name and the ID).

Thanks for your help!

I expected the Picker component to preselect the value based on the selected team's TID. However, the preselection is not happening, and the Picker remains unselected. I have verified that the selected team object is received correctly in NewMessageScreen and the selectedValue prop of the Picker is set to the correct TID value.

What I have tried so far:

Checked that the selectedValue prop in the Picker is correctly set to the selected team's TID value.
Ensured that the selectedTeam state is updated correctly in the NewMessageScreen component's componentDidMount method.
Verified that the Picker component renders the correct items and values.
Despite these efforts, the Picker does not show the preselected value. What am I missing or doing wrong? How can I achieve the functionality of preselecting the value in the Picker based on the selected team's TID?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!